Steep contango in near term VIX as nears expiry date
VIX futures expiry on 21 Aug.
VIX curve in very steep contango up to October.
Is there any evidence of this providing a market timing tool of any worth?
Thanks

VIX futures is the market pricing where the next 30-day realized volatility will be at that expiry. So for example,
VIV24 the Oct 16 2024 VIX contract is at ~18.16, significantly higher than near term (VIU24 the Sep 18 2024 future at 15.68, the almost expired VIQ24 with 2 days left at 15.26, the spot VIX at 14.80) because it covers S&P 500 RV in the period Oct 16 to Nov 15 and this 30 day period includes the US election happening on Nov. 5, 2024.
